# Facebook multiple fql queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have so queries

```
{
"users" : "SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT source_id FROM #stream)",
"stream" : "SELECT post_id, description, type, message, created_time, updated_time, source_id, attachment from stream where filter_key in ('others') and type in (46, 56, 66, 80, 128, 247, 308) and (message or description) ORDER BY created_time desc LIMIT 15",
"photos" :"select images, pid from photo where pid in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #stream)"

}
```

when I try to use access_token from graph explorer all goes fine. But if I use my access token of my app for user a got en error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

I found than if change last query and replace this code with real pid all goes fine. 
`SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #stream`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At random I managed it is achieved what I wanted.

Here working code:

```
{
"users" : "SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT source_id FROM #stream)",
"stream" : "SELECT post_id, description, type, message, created_time, updated_time, source_id, attachment from stream where filter_key in ('others') and type in (46, 56, 66, 80, 128, 247, 308) and (message or description) ORDER BY created_time desc LIMIT 15",
"photos" :"select images, pid from photo where pid in (SELECT attachment FROM #stream)"
}
```

as you can see I change `SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #stream` to `SELECT attachment FROM #stream`

I don't see logic in FQL at all now :(